# Pollard kangaroo for discrete logarithm

Tags: algorithms, elliptic-curves

I already made [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/83226/iterations-of-pollards-kangaroo-attack-on-elliptic-curves) in the crypto community. Because nobody could answer me, I wanted to ask here: I want to understand Pollards kangaroo attack on discrete logarithms. There are two important cases: The discrete logarithm problem DLP and the elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem ECDLP. For each of these cases there is a algorithm, which are pretty similar. On my original post you can find the algorithm for ECDLP.

My source for the DLP algorithm is [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_kangaroo_algorithm) and my source for the ECDLP is page 492 of the book [handbook of elliptic and hyperelliptic curve cryptography](http://www.mrjoeyjohnson.com/Documents/Cryptography/Handbook%20of%20%20Elliptic%20and%20%20Hyperelliptic%20%20Curve%20Cryptography.pdf). Both describe the math behind this algorithm.

My question: What does the parameter N do? In the DLP algorithm one chooses a N and in the ECDLP the tame kangaroo jumps N-times. I tried varying N but could not find any significant differences.

Comment: I tried to understand the question, but this hard. (And i suppose it may be harder than answering it.) The crypto community seems to like linking information from one question to an other one considering it as a reference for the setting, even if the link is an example or just a related question. We have pieces of code defining functions without calling them. The reader has to know the story and write possibly the own code that evaluates a function defined line `def kangaroo_search(basepoint, p, y, a, b, N):` followed by the definition - without any doc string. Well, i have the same question.

Comment: ... what is `N` above?! Please try to formulate a clear mathematical question, please give references. Please make clear which `N` from which reference, from which piece of code. Do we really need both ECDLP and DLP in the question? (Or one of them is maybe just to give more information, but potentially it also comes as a digression and the reader gets easily lost.) A clear example placed here, in the OP, may help a lot.